# Linq Query Timeout Forcefully

Tags: c#, linq

I want to forcefully timeout a query if it takes more than 1 minute & this is i want for only 1 query.

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
{
.... Code
var data = ctx.tbl.Where() ....
.... Code
var data1 = ctx.tbl.Where() ....
.... Code
var data2 = ctx.tbl.Where() ....
}
```

If i set timeout for Context it will apply to all the queries.
Is there any way to Timeout a particular Query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
What I actually do while working with this type of problem is:

- Create different methods and pass the out put of one to another.
- Or Store the records in the `Auto property` and access in the required methods.
- So if possible create the different methods for the `data1`, `data2` and `data3`.
- Below is the code.

**Method 1 for data:**

```
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
    {
      .... Code
      var data = ctx.tbl.Where() ...
    }
```

**Method 2 for data 1:**

```
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
    {
      .... Code
      var data1 = ctx.tbl.Where() ...
    }
```

**Method 3 for data 2:**

```
    using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
    {
      .... Code
      var data2 = ctx.tbl.Where() ...
    }
```